# Mental Poker: Kriegspiel tic-tac-toe

Tags: mental-poker

The SBMC comic shared [rules for a new version of tic-tac-toe](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/tic) today — I'm trying to figure out if there's a mental-poker/zero trustless version which could be played between two untrusting players (without the "monitor").

- Is there a way we can know this is *not* possible?
- Is there a way that this *is* possible?

The complex bit: the two players are playing on their own private tic-tac-toe boards (three each), and the fact that a square is already occupied by your opponent is *only* exposed *after* you play in that square.

I'm trying to learn more about how to approach problems like this, so any "working" would be useful too!

#### The rules

(From [SMBC](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/tic))

##### Setup

Requires 3 people: 2 players and 1 "monitor"

Each player has three private tic-tac-toe boards, which their opponent cannot see, but the monitor can. They are labeled A, B, and C.

There are also 3 public tic-tac-toe boards which everyone can see. These are also labeled A, B, and C.

##### Gameplay

Players take turns writing one symbol in one square on their private board. Squares that are occupied on a private board are also occupied on the corresponding public board.

Once a player draws a symbol on their private board, the monitor checks to see if their opponent has already occupied that square by writing a symbol on their private board.

If the square is already occupied, the player who tried to occupy it a second time loses their turn. The symbol in that occupied square is then drawn in the corresponding square of the public board.

##### Scoring

Whenever a player gets three in a row on a board, up-down, left-right, or diagonal, they get a point. The winning board is not publicly revealed, but players may no longer play on it.

##### Winning

Whoever has the most points when no more moves are possible wins.

Comment: Ambiguities: is scoring based on the 3 public boards only, or on any of the 9 boards as suggested by _"on a board"_? In the first case, there's no point to _"The winning board is not publicly revealed"_ since it can be determined by observing the evolution of the public boards, unless the two players are excluded from _"everyone"_ who can see the public boards (and then do players know their score and the other's score in real time?).

Answer (score 0):

If the game can be played with a trusted moderator, then it can be played without one by replacing the trusted moderator with a [secure multiparty computation protocol](https://securecomputation.org/). *Any* trusted party can be replaced by a suitable secure multiparty computation protocol, under some appropriate cryptographic assumption.